# VB.NET application not working as logged in user but works as 'other user'

Tags: vb.net, security, rights

I trying to find out why a VB.NET application has stopped working and gives the following error when opening:

> ************** Exception Text ************** System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at System.Object.GetType()    at
>   OneFrm1.Form1.sub_something(Object array1, Object O1, Object O2)    at
>   OneFrm1.Form1.add_square_op1_to_array(square_area_options& array1,
>   String v)    at OneFrm1.Form1.sub_something(Object array1, Object O1,
>   Object O2)    at OneFrm1.Form1.load_date_panel_format_array()    at
>   OneFrm1.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

The application works fine if I right click and run as 'another user' but gives the above error if running as the logged-in user.  I have tried a new user profile and it still gives the same error.  The same issue with security software removed.

The other user has the same rights.

Comment: Users have access rights to specific parts of the filesystem, for example. Maybe you're accessing a path that *another user* can access and the current user cannot. Then, if you have an empty `Catch` block, you eat up the exception when you access a *forbidden* resource and when you try to use an object that a failed procedure should have generated, this object is null. Just a possible cause, you should have some error logging in place.

Comment: Thanks, Jimi, when trying the other user they have the same rights (local admin).  One affected system is a screen display which has not been updated recently, no changes to the user account and has all of a sudden got this error.

Comment: Well, an *application has stopped working and gives the following error*, when the exception is a very generic one, is not very helpful. You should t least specify when/doing what you get the exception. On startup? What is the application supposed to do at this point? In a different moment? Same question.

Comment: I know and the creator of the application is no longer around.  I'm just trying to get it working again.  I have put the full error message in the post now.

Comment: You have a couple of methods that should generate/fill/use these `Object array1, Object O1, Object O2` on Form.Load. The type of these objects (`Object`) and the name of the methods `sub_something`, `load_date_panel_format_array` don't give much of a clue. This is a matter of debugging the application and logging functions results/exceptions.

Comment: Compile it with DEBUG configuration and start the application again. Then you see the line number on which the NullReferenceException occurs. Or in Visual Studio, hit Alt-Ctrl-E, ensure the debugger stops at managed exceptions and start the debugger with F5.

Comment: This is beyond my skill set and I would imagine that you would not get a NullReferenceException as the application works on 95% of the workstations